# Multilevel Master-Slave pattern using Actors in Akka

Tags: akka

I am trying to build an application using Akka.
The application will have a Master Actor which will distribute work to n-number of Slave Actors. Each of the Slave Actors will behave as a Master Actor for m-number of Slave Actors under it.

That is the Master Actor will provide tasks to Slaves Actors under it. Each Slave Actor is again going to redistribute the tasks given to it by the Master to the Slaves under it.

The mid level Actor thus behaves both as a Slave as well as a Master.

My question is that, is this architecture possible ?
If yes, what are the pros and cons ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is exactly the way you should work with actors in Akka. Actor hierarchy is the perfect way to deal with work distribution and failure handling. Why stop at three levels? Make as many levels as you deem useful and logical. This way if one actor encounters a problem, the application can easily recover.